# onbeforeunload dialog cancellation with window.location.href IE8 bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Sorry about the obscure title, hopefully I can explain:

I have a standard, "Are you sure you wish to leave" dialog that pops up when a user tries to leave a page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'You have unsaved changes';
}
```

When this is coupled with `window.location.href` **and the user clicking cancel** an 'Unspecified error' is thrown in internet explorer 8 or earlier. The same doesn't seem to happen with other modern browsers.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input').click(function() {
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; // error is thrown here
    });
</script>

<input type="button" value="Go to google" />
```

**Is there any way I can continue to use window.location.href and get around this bug in IE8?**

Comment: Sorry forgot the important note that it only happens when the user clicks cancel on the "Are you sure you wish to leave" dialog

Comment: Just a typo - question updated.

Comment: Have you tried simply setting `window.location` and not the `.href`?

Comment: FYI or somebody else: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/13000cd8-5c50-4260-a0d2-bc404764966d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a known IE bugs. I think you can just catch that error use try block.