# IE8 only jumps back to top of previous page not where I was before (but only with JS on)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have a horrible, scattered page with lots of JavaScript:

It has a list view and if you like you can watch one of the items in the list in detail.

The problem is now if I want to go back from the details view to the list view by using the browser back button I get different results.

In Chrome and Firefox, even in IE7 I will end up where I clicked, but not so in IE8.

To make it even more confusing, if I switch JavaScript off it works for IE8 as well.

The problem is now I don't now where to search. Does somebody know this problem or at least a JavaScript method or function which could affect this?

Comment: Maybe add a sort to the list? is it called from a db?

Comment: Possible reasons: page does client redirects via window.location = "herpderp" instead of window.location.replace(); page uses iframes which works not-so-obvious when we talk about history traversing, especially in IE.

Comment: Is the list view a third-party JS lib that you're using or one you've written yourself? If it's a third-party lib, please let us know which one.

Comment: @MattCain - Is your issue only on a "real" IE8? I don't have such an old version available, and it seems to work fine on IE10 in IE8 mode with JavaScript on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to provide a definitive answer without the code. A tentative answer based on past experiences with IE:

IEs have different behaviors, especially IE8 which is at the crossing of the old and all but standard versions [IE6-, IE7] and the newer IE9 that better sticks to standards. In particular in Javascript, IEs may be picky compared to non-IE browsers.

That *back* behavior could happen if a JS error is triggered either when you leave the page (thanks to the link click), or when you come back (which is easier to spot)

- Check if an error occurs when leaving (or coming back) at the bottom of the page
- The *click* action could be delayed thanks to `setTimeout` which function would set `window.location.href` to give you enough time to spot an error before the page is left
- If the redirect is "manual" (like `window.location.href=` as opposed to a simple `<a>` tag) Try to add a `try {} catch` around the code that run after the element is clicked (like with [this *onbeforeunload* bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264566/onbeforeunload-dialog-cancellation-with-window-location-href-ie8-bug)).